# MySQL Database Connection with PHP MySQL Extension

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm still new to PHP and haven't developed the knowledge of knowing how to fix most bugs when I anticipate them. I have a problem with connecting to a database the I have just created. I'm learning this example from a book. The browser keeps returning the result: "**Warning:** mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in: 'Path to the file'". I assume there's something wrong with $result, but please have a look at it. My code looks like this:

```
<?php

    // Open a MySQL connection
    $link = mysql_connect('xxx', 'xxx', 'xxx');
    if(!$link) {
        die('Connection failed' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Select the database to work with 
    $db = mysql_select_db('test');
    if(!$db) {
        die('Selected database unavailable: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    // Create and execute a MySQL query
    $sql = "SELECT artist_name FROM artists";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    // Loop through the returned data and output it
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        printf("Artist: %s<br />", $row['artist_name']);
    }

    // Free the memory associated with the query 
    mysql_free_result($result);

    // Close the connection
    mysql_close($link);

?>
```

Comment: You use the old `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated (see the [red box](http://php.net/mysql_query)). Switch to MySQLi or PDO. And `mysql_query` is apparently returning `FALSE`. What does your database look like?

Comment: Try to debug readin mysql_error: `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`. Also rember that `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, use `mysqli` or `PDO` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In case mysql_query fails, it returns false, a boolean value. When you pass this to mysql_fetch_array function (which expects a mysql result object) we get this error. Make sure that the query which you are using will fetch some result or you are using correct column name.

You should switch to use mysqli or PDO as others are suggesting.

Comment: The last sentence is not true: use prepared statements, which are available through the MySQLi and PDO interfaces.

Comment: @marcel Thanks for rectifying :)

Comment: You mean both Mysqli and PDO supports prepared statement ?

Comment: I read somewhere that mysqli does not support prepared statement. See the table here :- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/   Is it wrong ?

Comment: Yes, that table is wrong (even more, at the 'Named Parameters' section it actually gives an example of a prepared statement using MySQLi), see the page I linked to, which contains an example of a prepared statement with MySQLi. It's even the other way around: by default PDO simply escapes all instances of `'` when you think you are using prepared statements; you have to explicitly turn off `EMULATE_PREPARES` to use real prepared statements in PDO.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm still to see the section about using PDO. I thought there was something faulty in the book or my code. Let me check out if the same method will work with PDO...

Answer (score -1):

There are no problems in your code and the problem is in your Query.

Replace

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

With

```
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

And you will find what's wrong in your Query.